# I'm getting really unstable analog values with my B103348 joystick

Tags: analogread, joystick

I'm trying to make my B103348 joystick control a DC motor but I'm getting very unstable values from it specifically when the y axis is at 0. This is what my Serial monitor shows...

> 0,
> 21,
> 21,
> 21,
> 0,
> 22,
> 23,
> 21,
> 21...

This is the wiring...

[image]

And here's the code...

```cpp
int y_pin = A0;
int y_val;

int in_1 = 3;
int in_2 = 4;
int clock_wise_speed;
int counter_clock_wise_speed;

int en = 2;

int dt = 500;

void setup() {
pinMode(y_pin, INPUT);

pinMode(en, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in_1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in_2, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(2000000);
}

void loop() {
  //Clock wise = in_1 LOW and in_2 HIGH.
  //Counter clock wise = in_1 HIGH and in_2 LOW.
  y_val = analogRead(y_pin);
  clock_wise_speed = .21994 * y_val;
  counter_clock_wise_speed = 90;

  if(y_val >= 506){
    analogWrite(en, clock_wise_speed);
    digitalWrite(in_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in_2, HIGH);
  }

  if(y_val >= 501 and y_val <= 505){
    digitalWrite(en, LOW);
  }

  if(y_val <= 500){
    analogWrite(en, 225);
    digitalWrite(in_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in_2, LOW);
  }
  

Serial.println(y_val);
delay(dt);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: do you honestly believe that the picture shows clearly where each wire is connected? ... please draw a wiring diagram

Comment: *"specifically when the y axis"* If this is meant to imply that it behaves differently when wired to the x-axis, that should probably be spelled out.  Not being able to actually see the joystick or know its model, the distinction seems otherwise fairly meaningless.

Comment: @jsotola Is there a free software I can use to make a schematic for it?

Comment: If nothing else, you can hand draw it.  It doesn't have to be professional; just readable.  You could also retake your picture under good light, e.g. near a window during the day.

Comment: How stable to you *need* the values to be? You’re dealing with analog-to-digital conversion which will always bring some noise. If you need values that change less abruptly, run the raw *analogRead()* values through a filter (for example a simple moving average filter).

Comment: Personally I've used [Express PCB](https://www.expresspcb.com/) for free schematics. However you could just sketch out on a bit of paper how you wired up the joystick. I would test without what looks like a motor in your photo - that might be influencing things.

Comment: Could you try a sketch that does nothing other than `Serial.println(analogRead(A0)); delay(500);`?

Comment: There is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlDi0vO9Evg) which appears to be about your joystick. Can you perhaps try what is suggested there and report what happens?

Comment: 21/1023 possible readings is only 2%, perhaps that is normal for this joystick.

Comment: There is a schematic editor built into this website. Just edit your question and click the schematic button at the top of the editor.